# When I resize in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

Hey there can anyone please help me with this

When I resize the browser in IE then the two images display at the bottom initially all of them must display next to each other

All the HTML code is written in javascript you can't change anything in HTML however you can change the code in CSS

[image]

```css
div.card {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card .charts {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.card div.chart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
/*.card .chart { min-height: 200px; }*/

.card table.chart {
  min-height: 0;
}
.card div.chart:empty {
  display: none;
}
div.card > div.chart-name {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
div.card > div.chart-key {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  clear: both;
}
div.card > div.chart-key > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #dadada;
}
div.card > div.chart-key > span + span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #dfdfdf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #dfdfdf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card " data-tab="Climate Survey" data-tab_sub="Climate Survey" data-controluid="E215EDBB-055F-1995-ED3972A87BABCA7B"></div>
<div class="charts">
  <div id="Chart_Bar_4" class="chart" style="width: 441px; height: 300px;"></div>
  <svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" class="ct-chart-bar ct-horizontal-bars">
    <g class="ct-grids">
```

->

Comment: Post all relevant HTML -- but only the relevant part (and not necessarily all the content that's inside the different divs).

Comment: have you tried adding flex property to div.card??
or provide JsFiddle...

Comment: How do you add a flex property to the div.card can you perhaps give me an example please

Answer (score 1):

You have blocks with different heights and apply `float: left` to them.

There are different possible solutions:

- Ensure all blocks have the same height.
- Use `inline-block` instead of `float`.
- Use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is a fairly new feature but works really wel! I added two links give it a read and try it out.

[Youtube - Flexbox essentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg)

[Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Have a look at the 6 squares/divs are they all the same size? looks like maybe the 2 at te bottem are a few pixels wider